# How to update Redux dependent state object in tree?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am new to Redux and working on one React - Redux application.
At some point I am having issue with how to update Redux dependent state object in different branch of tree.
I have one property Thumbnail and one Process. I am getting Thumbnail and Process data by two different API call, on I am using mapDispatchToProps to fetch data and usign Action and Reducer i am storing both object property into state tree.
I need to filter process from Thumbnail and get Thumbnail based on filter result and need to store another object currentThumbnail into store tree.
fetching and storing Thumbnail and Process objects into state are working good, since currentThumbnail i can only get after filtering Thumbnail and Process, currentThumbnail always stays blank.
There would not be any button click or other user interaction action for currenThumbnail, it should be set asynchronously completed after completing the Thumbnail and Process into store.
I tried to put actions to store Thumbnail, Process and currentThumbnail into componentdidmount() but Thumbnail and Process get filled but currentThumbnail stays blank all the time.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: show us the related code

Answer (score 0):

You can create action setCurrentThumbnail and dispatch it inside componentDidUpdate. Not sure if it's the most elegant solution because if statement inside componentDidUpdate will be complicated and error prone. You have to check both of Thumbnail and Process are fetched successfully then make calculations and dispacth.

Edit:

To check whether request is successfully completed you can put `isFetching` and `failed` fields inside your store.

If you use action creator like described here https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2016/10/idiomatic-redux-why-use-action-creators/ . You can dispatch events like `REQUEST_STARTED`, `REQUEST_SUCCEEDED`, `REQUEST_FAILED` to manipulate `isFetching` and `failed` easily.

Comment: I am doing the same as you stated, but I dont find any way to check both Thumbnail and Process are fetched and stored successfully before dispatching the action for setCurrentThumbnail.

Comment: You can use action creator see https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2016/10/idiomatic-redux-why-use-action-creators/ . This way you can put isFetching parameter inside your store (as well as return code) and compare it to previous state. It should be false now and true in previous state.